# Using Mapscript to create a mapfile from scratch

Tags: python, mapserver, mapscript

Following a few online tutorials I have seen, I am trying to create a mapfile from scratch using mapscript.  However, when I try to create the layer object, I get an error in the **init** of mapscript.py; NameError: global name 'args' is not defined.

Does anyone see something obvious?  When I use a mapfile that already exists on disk, everything works as expected.

```
        # create a new mapfile from scratch
        self.map = mapscript.mapObj()
        self.map.save('temp.map')
        self.map.setSize(256,256)
        self.map.setExtent(-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0)
        self.map.units= mapscript.MS_DD
        self.map.imagecolor.setRGB(255,255,255)

        # create a layer for the raster
        self.layer = mapscript.layerObj(self.map) ----> ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        self.layer.name= 'tilesource'
        self.layer.type= mapscript.MS_RASTER
        self.layer.status = mapscript.MS_ON
        self.layer.data= rasterpath
```

Comment: Was this resolved somehow? I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://mapserver.org/mapscript/mapfile.html, creating a layer object works differently:

```
test_map = new mapscript.mapObj()
new_layer = new mapscript.layerObj()
li = test_map.insertLayer(new_layer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still get the same error with this approach.

Comment: Can you post the whole script? I can't see where it gets "global name 'args'" from.

Comment: The error is happening in mapscript.py, the SWIG generated wrapper.  Its occurring in the init function at Line 1264.  Do you want me to attach the mapscript.py file?

Comment: So "new mapscript.layerObj()" produces the same error like "mapscript.layerObj(self.map)"? (Notice keyword "new".) Which version of Mapserver are you running?

Comment: The new keyword isn't required for Python. These seem to be left over from the PHP examples.

Comment: How can we run a python mapscript file? Do we place it the server's DocumentRoot and run it in the browser like http://localhost/script.py  ???  Cause this way I'm getting my code printed in my browser  :(

Answer (score 3):

I am a mapserver developer and I have just committed a patch that should solve this issue.
See changeset [r12309](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/changeset/12039) for the details.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem when trying to create a new CLASS object. I've logged it as a bug as the SWIG wrappers seem incorrect for both layerObj and classObj. The args variable is defined in neither:

```
def __init__(self, map = None): 
    this = _mapscript.new_layerObj(map)
    try: self.this.append(this)
    except: self.this = this
    if 1:
          if args and len(args)!=0:
            self.p_map=args[0]
          else:
            self.p_map=None
```

http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/ticket/3940

Using MapServer 6.0 and Python SWIG bindings version 1.3.39